# UIScrollView Swift - Adding Images

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

I'm trying to get a simple color picker by adding the colors as Images into an `UIScrollView`.
I've used `UIScrollView`s before and never encountered any issues. This time nothing gets displayed no matter what I do. Double checked if the colors get picked right and everything seems to be fine. For some reason the colors don't get added to the `UIScrollView`.

```
func fillColorPicker(colors: Array<String>){
    for i in 0..<colors.count{
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = UIImage(named:     colors[i])
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        let xPosition = CGFloat(i) * imageView.frame.width
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: imageView.frame.width, height: self.colorPicker.frame.height)
        colorPicker.contentSize.width = imageView.frame.width * CGFloat(i+1)
        colorPicker.addSubview(imageView)
    }
}
```

Found something. Somehow the `imageView.frame.width` is always 0. I assumed it would take the width from the image file?

**Solution:**

```
func fillColorPicker(colors: Array<String>){
    for i in 0..<colors.count{
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 75, height: 75))
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: colors[i])
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit


        let xPosition = CGFloat(i) * imageView.frame.width
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: imageView.frame.width, height: self.colorPicker.frame.height)
        colorPicker.contentSize.width = imageView.frame.width * CGFloat(i+1)
        colorPicker.addSubview(imageView)
    }
}
```

Comment: When you do `let xPosition = CGFloat(i) * imageView.frame.width` At this time, `imageView.frame.width` is 0, no? I think that you use the same images, so set the width to a constant: `let width = 50; let xPosition = CGFloat(i) * width, imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: width, ...); colorPicker.contentSize.width = xPosition + width`

Comment: This solved it. Thanks!